# service to check device state

Tags: java, android, background

I need to create an android service that:

- Starts whenever the screen is on (whether it is at boot time or not)
- sends a notification every 20 minutes (if the screen is on)
- stops whenever the screen is off

Every tutorial I've read uses an activity, but I need this to be a service because the app is not supossed to be running other than when the user wants to change a setting. The documentation says I need an IntentService, but I cannot stop that manually and I cannot use a Service because it is a long running operation. I tried with an alarm manager but it didn't worked, I don't even bother to show you the code because I really don't understand it. I do not know how to make the service check if the screen is on or not, if I use a BroadcastReceiver it won't be inmediately processed so I am just stuck

Comment: You are going to run into issues, as Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON can't be declared in your manifest so you have to register them via an IntentFilter in Java. PowerManager might have some options to help you.

Comment: @zgc7009 I checked the documentation and I think isInteractive() could help me, but I still have the issue of making the service start when the screen is on, and sending the notification. BTW should I use a service or an intent service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement your requirement. You need 3 things such as Service, BroadcastReceiver & AlarmManager :

1. AlarmManager [which will fire after every 20 minutes]
2. Service [which will make changes like showing notification as system gets notifies after every 20 minutes for your particular msg]
3. BroadcastReceiver [which will check for screen on/off right from booting to shutting down]

Refer these links :

1. http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/
2. http://androidexample.com/Screen_Wake_Sleep_Event_Listner_Service_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=91&aaid=115

Comment: thanks for the answer, I only need two things to be cleared. So... I create the broadcast receiver to send the intent to my service, if the action sent by the intent is ACTION_SCREEN_ON set the alarm (which will send the notifocation when it goes off), or if the action is ACTION_SCREEN_OFF I cancel the alarm, right? And well I need a service rather than an IntentSercive, right?

Comment: You just need "Service". Keep it simple.